# Getting total number of registered users

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my app I have login/registration system and need to count the total number of registered users. For example I have 2 registered users.

```
----------------------------------------------------
|id|    email      |use_name|user_pass|confirm_pass|
----------------------------------------------------
|7 | theo@gmail.com|  theo  | my pass |   my pass  |
----------------------------------------------------
|8 | test@gmail.com|  test  | my pass |   my pass  |
----------------------------------------------------
```

The is a function in mysql called SUM,but it adds ints.In my case though the id is incrementing from the last deleted user.

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: `select COUNT(id) registered_users from your_table`..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use mysql_num_rows on your query.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Considering moveing away from mysql to mysqli or PDO if you are a new.
Instead of learning an outdated and no more supported mysql.

Comment: Highly inefficient to select using 'where 1=1' and use mysql_num_rows just to count, Sougata`s solution to use an aggregate function COUNT() is faster